# Dividing a page into blocks/parts

Tags: latex

I'm trying to write a resume using latex and want to divide the page up in smaller sections(education, experience, skills, etc). However, I'm not really sure how to achieve this. A lot of the templates that i have found basically looks like a list, sometimes with a sidebar, but I want to be able to have a header and sections next to each other. Think CSS grids. The only tool I have found is Flowfram, but it feels overly complicated. Is there an easier way to achieve this layout?

Even though this isn't my type of resume, it gives a good idea of the type of layout I want to achieve:

[image: Layout Example]

Comment: Can you make a sketch of the layout you want? Many latex resumes are simply based on some tabular environment.

Comment: Of course! Updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alignment of the content seems to be independent between the two columns, so one could use a very simple layout and just place two minipages besides each other:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}

\Huge\centering
Quack McDucky
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\Large Duckxpert
\end{minipage}%

\vspace{2cm}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.55\textwidth}
\section*{Work Experience}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\raisebox{-.425\textheight}{\rule{1pt}{.45\textheight}}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.35\textwidth}
\section*{Education}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}%


\end{document}
```

[image]